# random word generator that re-rolls if it generate a specific word

Tags: c#, exception, random

I'm trying to make a random word generator that re-rolls if the generated word is "empty slot"
but I get an error "exception unhandled" if the generated word is "empty slot" [image: error] at `Random r = new Random();`:

```
 System.StackOverflowException
```

my code:

```
public void rdwrd()
{
    Random r = new Random();

    string[] words = { word1, word2, word3, word4, word5, word6, word7, word8, word9, word10, word11, word12, word13, word14, word15, word16, word17, word18, word19, word20, word21, word22 };
    if((words[r.Next(0, words.Length)]) == "empty slot")
    {
        rdwrd();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(words[r.Next(0, words.Length)]);

        answerbox.Text = (words[r.Next(0, words.Length)]);
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate if anybody could help

Comment: so if what happens on "empty slot" is that you reroll - why don't you just cut "empty slot" from the generator alltogether? also: please work on your intendation. _a lot_. unformatted code is not just painful to look at, but a breeding ground for bugs. and error messages are text, too, so include it _as text_ in your question, thank you.  i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: because im making text boxes to write the words u want it to choose from, so if you write "empty slot" it wont choose from this box, im sorry about the code im still new to coding

Comment: You should create only a single instance of the `Random` class (e.g. as field of your class) . Otherwise, the result of `r.Next` tends to be the same every time.

Comment: What if all the words are “empty slot”? … you have an infinite loop then. Is this a lesson in recursion? Recursion seems unnecessary for this.

Comment: Put the contents of the method inside a loop, instead of the method calling itself. You are constructing new instances of Random on every call, and since they happen so fast, and Random is based on current time, it will regenerate the same sequence of random numbers for a lot of those calls, which is why you get a StackOverflowException. Make sure you construct the Random object *outside* of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is using more than one `Random` object. You should use only one. Another problem is using recursion where a simple loop could do the job. Third problem is generating random values more than once, so the word that you check for equality is not the word that you output to console, which is not the word that goes to the edit box.

```
private Random r = new Random();

public void rdwrd()
{
    string[] words = { word1, word2, word3, word4, word5, word6, word7, word8, word9, word10, word11, word12, word13, word14, word15, word16, word17, word18, word19, word20, word21, word22 };

    for (;;)
    {
        string word = words[r.Next(0, words.Length)];

        if (word != "empty slot")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);

            answerbox.Text = word;

            break;
        }
    }
}
```